# Symfony cache dont work with class/object

Tags: php, symfony, object, caching, serialization

I use some php library, and generate element of class

```
 $elnew = new LibClass();
```

I want to save this variable to cache.
If I make like this

```
$elem = $cache->getItem($ig_name);
if (!$elem->isHit()) {
  $elem->set($elnew);
  $cache->save($ig);
}
```

`$elem->isHit()` is always false. I checked how cache works with string - all is ok.
Also I'm not able to serialyze/unserialyze this object because it says

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

and no way to modify `LibClass`

How can I save `$elnew` to cache? Any variants for with symfony components? Or maybe other libs can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

You can use the [PHP SuperClosure library](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure) to get rid of this.

Also you can try other memory storages like **[Redis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjmgqfUj8HbAhVM1hQKHV6mBiYQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fredis.io%2F&usg=AOvVaw0SPzotNaWJKDkbJZ8FW9ft)** or **Memcache** to cache your objects. See this [resolved stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931578/best-method-to-cache-objects-in-php).

Comment: You are right about the SuperClousure, but be careful about [its restrictions](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure#caveats).
And only to be clear: Redis and Memcache aren't libraries, they are external in-memory storages. Symfony Cache already supports them and [many others](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html#available-simple-cache-psr-16-classes).

Comment: @Timurib yes my bad they aren't libraries. But Symfony cache does not support closure serialization that's why I proposed them.

Comment: I try this lib and some similar. They don't work in my variant, they don't like that my object is really class instance